# JME APPLET (browser can’t load library )

Tags: java, applet, jmonkeyengine

I created simple JME Applet but I’ve problem with natives libraries. When I run it I get error. This error disappear and all work fine when I move libraries to catalog which is showed in java console. The following example work good too: http://jmonkeyengine.com/demo/applet/ . It’s looks like extraction doesn’t work properly.

```
paź 06, 2012 9:02:32 PM com.jme3.system.JmeDesktopSystem initialize
INFO: Running on jMonkeyEngine 3.0.0 Beta
paź 06, 2012 9:02:32 PM com.jme3.system.Natives extractNativeLibs
INFO: Extraction Directory: C:Users/manio/AppData/Local/GoogleChrome/Application/22.0.1229.79/
paź 06, 2012 9:02:32 PM com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglCanvas$GLCanvas addNotify
INFO: EDT: Creating OGL thread.
paź 06, 2012 9:02:32 PM com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglCanvas$GLCanvas addNotify
INFO: EDT: Telling OGL to create display ..
Exception in thread “LWJGL Renderer Thread” java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can’t load library: C:Users/manio/AppData/Local/GoogleChrome/Application/22.0.1229.79/lwjgl.dll
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:70)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66)
at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:95)
at org.lwjgl.Sys.(Sys.java:112)
at com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglAbstractDisplay.run(LwjglAbstractDisplay.java:206)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: *"I created simple JME Applet"*  What is a *JME Applet*?  I understand both `java.applet.Applet` (J2SE) & `javax.swing.JApplet` (J2SE), but have never heard of an applet for ME.

Comment: Uh-huh.  Try reading the info. on the tags you add to posts.  Java-ME ***does not*** stand for Java Monkey Engine.